# Crear una nueva columna dataframe con Python en función otras dos columnas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una columna A y otra columna B en un dataframe. Quería saber cómo conseguir que se añada una nueva columna C a mi dataframe en el que ponga 'Verdadero' si los valores (en este caso son objects) para cada fila de las columnas A y B coinciden y 'Falso' si no lo hicieran.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenida Cristina a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes construir esa columna C directamente comparando las dos series:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] == df['B']
```

También puedes usar numpy.where para construirla:

```
import numpy as np

df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] == df['B'], 'Verdadero', 'Falso')
```